# Authorize.net support for Bin number Check (card issuer identification number )feature

Tags: authorize.net

In my project I am using authorize.net AIM & CIM feature for payment processing, I want to implement real time verification of card holder during transaction using authorize.net & asp.net (C#) in order to provide higher level of security and avoid fraud transaction.

Today, I want confirm that ,
Is it possible to verify [BIN number](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/bank-identification-number.asp) (Credit card Issuer Identification number) of credit card from card number using authorize.net ?
How can I check  BIN number of credit card with authorize.net  in  real time  from credit card number which will support for all types of credit card such Visa, Master Card, American Express, Discover etc.

Comment: Authorize.Net does not offer validation of BIN numbers and you shouldn't need to anyway. What matters is if the credit card is valid.

Comment: So my question is how can I verify card holder's identity in real time  to avoid any fraud during transaction processing by confirming only authorize card holder is doing transaction & is applicable for all types of credit card & is applicable for authorize.net's  AIM & CIM methods of integration in asp.net (C#) ?

Comment: You can't validate identities with credit cards. And the only way to validate a credit card is valid is to process a transaction with it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately authorize.net does not offer BIN number validation. If you have the access to first 6 digits of credit card or BIN number, you can pass it to [FraudLabs Pro](http://www.fraudlabspro.com) API  to access for BIN information.

FraudLabs Pro is a free fraud screening service for SMB with less than 500 transactions per month. It has other validation features other than BIN validation requested.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a free tier BIN check: https://tripayments.com/bins/.  Threshold is 10 requests a second before an upgraded version is required.  I've used it in the past for detecting fraud.  Supports an array bins instead of singles.

Answer (score 0):

There are 7 Steps of the Credit Card Process from [Authorize.net](https://www.authorize.net/resources/howitworksdiagram/)

> The STEP 4: The issuing bank approves or declines the transaction
>   based on the customer's available funds and passes the transaction
>   results back to the credit card network.

So, you can call the Payment Transactions API, Authorize a Credit Card method request, then you will get a [transactionResponse.responseCode](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#payment-transactions-authorize-a-credit-card), which is one of the following:
1 -- Approved
2 -- Declined
3 -- Error
4 -- Held for Review